# Ruby on Rails - Admin User View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, admin

I am working on a Ruby on Rails application in which a user has many posts and each post has many comments.

In the Admin/view/user.erb file, how would one output to the screen all of:

*the user's posts?

*the comments for each post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In users table add boolean column admin and set 1 if you want that user to be admin

In user model define

```
def is_admin?
    admin == true 
end
```

In contoroller user action

```
@users = User.all
```

In user.erb file, You can list out all users

```
- @users.each do |user|
    = link_to user.name, show_users_path(user)
```

In controller show action

```
def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

then in show page

```
= @user.name 
- @user.posts.each do |post|
    = post.data
    - post.comments.each do |comment|
        = comment.data
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd presumably have the user's id in the url somewhere: by convention, your path might be

```
/admin/users/:id
```

which goes to the show action of the Admin:UsersController

this has something like

```
@user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
```

and in your view you have

```
<% @user.posts.each do %>
  <div class="user-post">
    <div class="posted-at">Posted at <%= post.created_at.strftime("%d/%m/%Y") %></div>
    <div class="post-body">
      <%= post.body %>
    </div>
    <% post.comments.each do |comment| %>
      <div class="comment">
        <div class="posted-at">Posted at <%= comment.created_at.strftime("%d/%m/%Y") %></div>
        <div class="post-body">
          <%= comment.body %>
        </div>    
      </div>    
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

which you can obviously tailor to suit your requirements.

This is all super-basic stuff.  Have you read much about rails?  This is the sort of thing a scaffold generator would make for you.